# How to version an Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm still at the path of learning programming, but my apps are getting quite complicated and I want to learn how to store a snapshot of current working app version before continuing with implementing other enhancements so that I could go back to that stored version if need be? Could anyone give me a link to tutorial about it? My search only returns tips how to set app version in gradle files.

Comment: You should take a look at Git. https://github.com/

Comment: What about offline solutions? Is it possible to automate it with Android Studio instead of creating folders for each project of different version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for I believe is a source control software that will be able to control your versioning, there are plenty, I recommend:  **Git**

Tutorials:

- [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/git/)
- [Tutorial for begginers by Roger Dudler](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

One of Git concept is being able to work offline (you can work locally on your PC).

**AndroidStudio Integration:**

After installing Git on your machine you can easily integrate Git with AndroidStudio (Although I prefer working from Git Bash CLI), by doing:

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git and configure Git
2. Go to VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration -> select 'Git'

Answer (score 1):

**You should take a look at [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.htmlhttps://github.com/)**

for a starter I recommend

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/git/
2. http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/
3. https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/